# Is there any difference in performance in using AND and WHERE during joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am joining two tables with half a million records each and this is the structure of both tables

```
A (AKey, Name)
B (BKey, AKey, Value, Set).
```

Set is a bit type. No index on Set.

Is there any difference between these two queries?

```
SELECT Name, Value
FROM A
INNER JOIN B 
    ON A.AKey = B.Key 
    AND B.Set = 1
```

and

```
SELECT Name,Value
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE B.Set = 1
```

These two return the same results. Might be a noob question but still a question.

Comment: There should be no difference in performance but there would be a big difference in result if it would be a `left join` for instance

Comment: What were the results of your own personal tests?

Comment: @Dan The execution plans for the data set that I used did not give much difference in performance. This data set might increase. That is why I want to use the query that is better